# How to re-interpret 'source code' of special chars

Tags: c++, c, encoding

I am writing a program (c++, Windows) that parse a rdf-xml file (UTF-8 encoded) using Raptor RDF librairies.
Everything happens fine, except when the parser find a literal value containing special chars (such as 'µ' '°' '²' etc). In these cases, the parser return a non interpreted string.
For instance, if the parser find the literal value :

> blaµbla

it will return a char tab containing :

> "bla\u00B5bla"

(the quotes are not an error, the returned string **is** surronded by ' " ').

I say that this string is non-interpreted, because if I write it directly in my code, i will have the expected result :

```
std::string test("bla\u00B5bla"); printf(test.c_str());
```

output :

> blaµbla

If i wanted to reproduce the string returned by th Raptor parser, i should do :

```
std::string test("\"bla\\u00B5bla\""); printf(test.c_str());
```

output :

> "bla\u00B5bla"

So, my question is : how to re-interpret special chars in a string ?
I've made some research but i could not find anything to answer this.
Any help would be very usefull and appreciated, thanks.

EDIT1 : 
Here some simplified code showing how i got the 'non-interpreted' string :

```
void triple_handler(void* user_data, raptor_statement* triple) {
    if (triple->object->type == RAPTOR_TERM_TYPE_LITERAL){
        printf((char*) raptor_term_to_string(triple->object));
    }
}
```

output (assuming that the original literal value in the file is : blaµbla) :

> "bla\u00B5bla"

My goal is only to recover the original correct string from that.

Comment: What is your goal? This type of question screams "[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)".

Comment: I would guess his goal is to have character 'µ' in a string, instead of text of 6 characters "\u00B5".

Comment: Bwadrochit, could you add a small piece of code of using Raptor that is causing you grief?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other way like ask that library to output Unicode strings, or translate Unicode chars base on current charset, etc.

Or you can do something like this (**just pseudo code, and maybe wrong, just give you some hints that you can convert the string to wstring yourself**):

```
wstring foo(string in_src)
{
    wstring out = L"";

    for (auto i = in_src.begin(), e = in_src.end(); i != e;)
    {
        if (*i != '\\')
        {
            out += (wchar_t)*i;

            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (e - i > 1 && *(i + 1) == '\\')
            {
                out += L'\\';

                i += 2;
            }
            else if (e - i > 4)
            {
                wchar_t c;

                if (convert_next_4_chars_as_hex_number_by_whatever_means(i + 1, c))
                {
                    out += c;

                    i += 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw some_error;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw some_error;
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is half of a solution for me, because I don't know how to implement the convert_next_4_chars_as_hex_number_by_whatever_means() function here. Of course I could make my own personal mapping to do this but I would rather avoid this and use some 'standard' function, if any exists.

Comment: @Bwadrochit You can use `sscanf` or `istringstream`. But in this case implement your own method is much easier.